# Corrupted "cout" library?

Tags: c++, cout, clion

OK, so here is what i got going on. I use the latest version of Clion by JetBrains. I run the MinGW GUI as a compiler and use the bundled CMake that comes with the GUI.

So here is my code.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        cout << j << " ";
    }
    cout << "   LINE: " << i;
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Very simple and this is what it should output

```
1    LINE: 1
1 2    LINE: 2
1 2 3    LINE: 3
1 2 3 4    LINE: 4
```

And it continues up until 30.

I know that the actual code is correct because when I run it on a different compiler (On an Ubuntu VM) it comes out perfectly. But when I run it on Clion this is the output:

```
1    LINE: 1
1 2    LINE: 2
1 2 3    LINE: 3
1 2 3 4    LINE: 4
1 2 3 4 5    LINE: 5
1 2 3 4 5 6    LINE: 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7    LINE: 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    LINE: 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9    LINE: 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10    LINE: 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11    LINE: 11
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12    LINE: 12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13    LINE: 13
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14    LINE: 14
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15    LINE: 15
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16    LINE: 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 71 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17    LINE: 17
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18    LINE: 18
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19    LINE: 19
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20    LINE: 20
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21    LINE: 21
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22    LINE: 22
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23    LINE: 23
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24    LINE: 24
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25    LINE: 25
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26    LINE: 26
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27     LINE: 27
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 181 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14   15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28    LINE: 28
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29    LINE: 29
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30    LINE: 30
```

Ya, so that clearly doesn't work. And and to solidify the fact that its not my code, when I run it again...

```
1    LINE: 1
1 2    LINE: 2
1 2 3    LINE: 3
1 2 3 4    LINE: 4
1 2 3 4 5    LINE: 5
1 2 3 4 51 2 3 4 5 6    LINE: 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7    LINE: 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    LINE: 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9    LINE: 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10    LINE: 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11    LINE: 11
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12    LINE: 12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13    LINE: 13
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14    LINE: 14
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15    LINE: 15
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16    LINE: 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17    LINE: 17
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18    LINE: 18
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19    LINE: 19
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20    LINE: 20
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21    LINE: 21
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22    LINE: 22
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23    LINE: 23
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24    LINE: 24
1 2 3 4 5 6 71 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25    LINE: 25
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26    LINE: 26
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27    LINE: 27
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28    LINE: 28
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29    LINE: 29
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30    LINE: 30
```

And if ran it again it would once again be different. It never the same and is always doing the same thing more or less.

This issue only seems to exist when I run programs that spit out long cout's. For example the HelloWorld runs fine. And as the last kick in the nuts, I ran it on my other computer (same setup with Clion and MinGW) and the exact same thing was happening.

Comment: You're code runs as expected for me using ubuntu gcc version 4.8.4

Comment: Perhaps this is a CLion problem.

Comment: try using stringstream before uotputting to cout and see what happens then

Comment: CLion is not a compiler.  Please specify the compiler that you're using (probably some version of `gcc`).  Second, what happens when you leave your programming environment and just run the program on the command-line?  Do you see the same issue?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, He mentioned mingw. But it also runs fine for me on mingw gcc version 4.9.2

Comment: Did you try running through *Valgrind* or compiling with a sanitizer?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie CLion's not a compiler, but it probably deals with the input and output files when it needs to display or embed the console. That program is extremely simple--why would `cout` be broken, of all things? The problem is most likely CLion's fault.

Comment: @AlexValente Try replace `endl;` with `'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick responces.
@VermillionAzure I just tried and its still doing the same thing.

Comment: @DylanJamesMcGannon So i actually have MinGW 4.8.1, so I'm about to go get 4.9.2 and see if it works any better. And I do think its just a CLion issue, but what?!?! It just doesn't make sense. Even when I build the program and run the Debug .exe via CMD there is nothing there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ya, I realize that CLion is only an environment, but the im guessing the libraries that it uses must me broken somewhere, The Compiler I'm using is MinGW 3.21. My current GCC is MinGW32-gcc 4.8.1 (going to up to 4.9.2 as I type)

Comment: @engf-010 I did that, and it actualy works, but that just adds a unnecessary code and although it would fix the problem here and now, long term I want cout to work as cout should.

Comment: @AlexValente I don't think changing anything related to GCC is going to help you. You may want to switch over to MinGW-w64 because the main MinGW branch wasn't doing that well with regards to bug-fixing and 64-bit compatibility.

Comment: The next thing you can try is redirecting stdout to a file. If that doesn't have problems you know that the problem lies with 'mapping' to the underlying device (a monitor is not really a stream).

Comment: It's definetly CLion (or it's settings and console behaviour) problem. I have same way corrupted output in CLion console. Standart windows console output is fine. Some lines printed partially twice.